# Is there a way to use JSON schemas to enforce values between fields?

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I've recently started playing with [JSON schemas](http://json-schema.org/) to start enforcing API payloads. I'm hitting a bit of a roadblock with defining the schema for a legacy API that has some pretty kludgy design logic which has resulted (along with poor documentation) in clients misusing the endpoint.

Here's the schema so far:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "type": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "object_id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "question_id": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "^-1|\\d+$"
            },
            "question_set_id": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "^-1|\\d+$"
            },
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time"
            },
            "values": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "type",
            "object_id",
            "question_id",
            "question_set_id",
            "timestamp",
            "values"
        ],
        "additionalProperties": false
    }
}
```

Notice that for **question_id** and **question_set_id**, they both take a numeric string that can either be a -1 or some other non-negative integer.

My question: is there a way to enforce that if **question_id** is set to -1, that **question_set_id** is also set to -1 and vice-versa.

It would be awesome if I could have that be validated by the parser rather than having to do that check in application logic.

---

Just for additional context, I've been using python's jsl module to generate this schema.

Comment: Try `"^-1|[\\d]+$"` for the `pattern`. Groups do not make sense here and you do not want to match `-11`.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks @flaschbier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behavior by adding the following to your `items` schema.  It asserts that the schema must conform to at least one of the schemas in the list.  Either both are "-1" or both are positive integers. (I assume you have good reason for representing integers as strings.)

```
"anyOf": [
    {
        "properties": {
            "question_id": { "enum": ["-1"] },
            "question_set_id": { "enum": ["-1"] }
        }
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "question_id": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "^\\d+$"
            },
            "question_set_id": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "^\\d+$"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah... integers as strings wouldn't have been my first choice. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a try.